# Отображение списка всех товаров на одной странице

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, список

Здравствуйте все, мне нужен совет.

Есть каталог товаров, созданный через woocommerce (cms wordpress, тема не поддерживает магазин) - всего 1300 наименований. На самом деле из всего этого каталога необходимо только: наименование товара, категория товара и цена. Все остальное не нужно - нужен только прейскурант (по факту), который надо отобразить в виде таблицы, сгруппированной по категориям.

Логичный вопрос: зачем для этого woocommerce, ведь есть масса плагинов для таблиц любого содержания?
Все просто: на других страницах тоже нужно отображать отдельные "избранные" товары, и чтобы не менять стоимость в десятке таблиц, было решено обратиться к woocommerce, и использовать мизерную часть его функционала.

В настоящий момент: нашел плагин для быстрого отображения на любой странице перечня товаров и с помощью CSS настроил отображение. Однако, CSS не решил проблему полностью, поскольку часть параметров все-равно запрашивается из БД, хоть и не отображается. И это приводит к тому, что на странице с прейскурантом не отображается вообще ничего (при статистике посещений всего-лишь около 300 в сутки).

Вопрос: можете ли посоветовать применить какой-то конкретный скрипт или запрос, чтобы облегчить загрузку из БД? Долго искал похожие проблемы, но ничего не нашел, чтобы кто-то использовал настолько ограниченный функционал woocommerce.

Вот пример кода, таких таблиц около 30 штук, по каждой категории. Сделать одну таблицу на все 1300 наименований невозможно, поскольку в этом случае вообще выдается ошибка.

```
<table class="price-header">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="price-header-name">
<h2>Наименование</h2>
</td>
<td class="price-header-cost">
<h2>Стоимость</h2>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
[product_category category="категория1" per_page="1000" columns="1" orderby="default" order="ASC" operator="IN"]
```

В любом случае, о такого варианта я намерен отказаться, но как можно облегчить запрос?

Comment: Сочувствую!!)) Пока не поздно, я бы переделал на вордпресс без вукоммерса, товары - как страницы со своим шаблоном, опции товара или атрибуты через ACF. Менять цены можно через кастомный скрипт. ЧТо еще? А, на страницу выводить все равно через пагинацию, 1000 товаров на ОДНОЙ никогда на любом движке не будут выводиться, падает браузер, а не движок!

Comment: Мне собственно даже переход на страницы не нужен. Нужен только сам список.

Comment: Я вижу такой костыль: сделать файл формирования такого списка с заданным шагом и сохранить результат в файл. Далее поставить это на крон или по требованию, а вывод сделать через инклуд файла. Есть еще совсем простой вариант, это сделать отдельную страницу с циклом на все продукты, но выводить с пагинацией.

Comment: Создайте кастомный тип записи products без вукоммерса, и выводите как и где нужно.  Если продуктов много лучше сделать постраничную навигацию, или подгрузку товара(каждые 10 например)  на AJAX при скроле или по кнопке.

Comment: да как вы не поймете - список - это значит будут элементы! все что выше 1000-2000 элементов DOM  - будет тормозить брауз! тем более таблица, которая заставляет браузер грузить ее полностью, а не кусками как div-ы. а еще остальные элементы верстки? в некоторых шаблонах их может до 200-400 набежать! я похожее решал год назад. поройтесь у меня))) ахах. я решил через вывод 5000 точек в виде одного элемента map и вложенных area - браузер отнесся благосклонно. ну это к примеру. таблицу в 1000-2000 строк браузер не выведет, особенно если взять любой планшет, вообще в перезагрузку уйдет в цикле

Comment: вам для чего вообще выводить столько? человек не может охватить сразу столько элементов) используйте ajax-подгрузку или как вариант, если вам надо сделать типо прайса для скачки - так и формируйте сразу файл!

Comment: Поддержу мнение коллег - если продажи с сайта (корзина и тп) не нужно - WC сильно избыточнен. Можно самому кастомный тип создать (я за это, это не сложно), а можно использовать готовые плагины каталогов товара. Но они тоже как правило навороченные и груЗные.

Comment: А для прейскуранта можно использовать плагины таблиц с постраничной навигацией и фильтрацией данных.

Comment: Все плагины сами по себе навороченные, ведь любому разработчику нет смысла делать плагин для масс узко-специальный.

Comment: Я как раз понимаю, что количество запросов в базу перегружает. В файл мне не нужно, файл прейскуранта есть отдельно, я им не занимаюсь. Заказчик просто хочет, чтоб через Ctrl+F всегда можно было найти любую услугу.